# How can I Get MIME type of bytea stored in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, arrays, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3, bytea

How can we get mime-type of bytea 
stored in Postgres database?

Comment: By storing it in another column in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is a bit late but would help some other.

As suggested by @craig-ringer I have implemented the mime-magic in `plpythonu`, so I can use the function in my INSERT/UPDATE-Trigger.

On the database server install `plpythonu` for your postgresql version (e.g. via `apt-get` or `yum`). No database restart/reload is needed, so it could be done in production easily.

Then install the python module `magic` on the database server:

```
pip install python-magic
```

After that create the plpythonu language in your database:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Now you can write database functions in python (even import python modules):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mimemagic(data bytea) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    import magic
    return magic.from_buffer(data, mime=True)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

If python2 is used, postgresql's `BYTEA` type maps to python's `string` type.
For python 3 it maps to pythons `bytes` type.

After you have created the function, you can use the plpythonu function in any statement or trigger-function like any other postgresql function.
To test our function, we can create a table like below and insert some files:

```
CREATE TABLE public.files (
  file_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('files_file_id_seq'::regclass),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  extension TEXT,
  content BYTEA NOT NULL,
  mime_type TEXT
);
```

Example query:

```
SELECT name, extension, mime_type, mimemagic(content) FROM files;
```

Result:

```
             name                 | extension | mime_type |    mimemagic     
----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----
 10868_170915_1M                  | pdf       |           | application/pdf
 30567_160415_1M                  | pdf       |           | application/pdf
 Diode-SCS                        | dxf       |           | text/plain
 Config                           | zip       |           | application/zip
 btn-default-medium-focus-corners | gif       |           | image/gif
 _loadmask                        | scss      |           | text/plain
 mr                               | json      |           | text/plain
 10549_160415_2M                  | pdf       |           | application/pdf
 disconnect                       | png       |           | image/png
```

As you can see no mime_type is saved in the table but mime-type is detected on demand.

No need to say that executing a function for every row on every query is a huge performance hit so the mime type detection should be done on INSERT/UPDATE and cached:

Example trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION files_trigger()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') OR (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND new.content IS DISTINCT FROM old.content)
  THEN
    new.mime_type := mimemagic(new.content);
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER files_insertupdate_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON files
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE files_trigger();
```

Mime Type is now detected once and saved next to the filecontent:

```
SELECT name, extension, mime_type FROM files;
```

Result:

```
                   name                   | extension |          mime_type           
------------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------
 teamviewer_10.0.35509_amd64              | deb       | application/x-debian-package
 BDFE999CCC39110229563FA8C8583E239F6BDBA1 | log       | text/plain
 daccr-Download                           | exe       | application/x-dosexec
```

To get better results, you should, when available, also try a detection based on filename/-extension since mimemagic alone fails for some types (json-File is detected as text/plain).
Also maybe play with magic's options like `uncompress=True` which may give more usable results:

```
>>> import magic
>>> import mimetypes
>>> filename='verybig.json.gz'
>>> m=magic.Magic(mime=True, uncompress=False)
>>> m.from_file(filename)
'application/gzip'
>>> m=magic.Magic(mime=True, uncompress=True)
>>> m.from_file(filename)
'text/plain'
>>> mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
('application/json', 'gzip')
>>>
```

Documentation for plpythonu can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpython.html

Code and documentation for python's magic module can be found here: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to definitively know the MIME type other than assigning it to another field when you store the `bytea` in the first place.

Presuming you have byte arrays of unknown type that represent files or other reasonably complete objects that could have a MIME type, you can use MIME-type guessing tools much like you can on files. These tools are far from perfect, but work well for common well-behaved file types with regular and predictable headers.

There's no such tool built in to PostgreSQL, but PostgreSQL supports invoking procedural languages like PL/Python and PL/Perl. These languages *do* have MIME type guessing tools.

So I suggest writing a wrapper function in PL/Perl or PL/Python that uses an appropriate MIME type guessing library to probe a `bytea` argument and return the guessed MIME type. Details of library selection and implementation are left as an exercise to the reader; I'd start with the PostgreSQL manual on PL/Perl or PL/Python, whichever you prefer to use.

Comment: Can you tell me about that PL/Perl or PL/Python scripts and how can I apply them in Postgres.

Comment: @ripunj2408813 [plpython](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html), [plperl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) . You will need to write a procedure in Perl or Python using appropriate libraries like Perl's `File::Type` or Python's mimetypes or Python-Magic libraries. Have a go. If you get stuck, post a new question with appropriate details showing what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I am not aware of Perl scripts.Can you provide me the PERL script to get the mime type of bytea in Postgres.

Comment: @ripunj2408813 Please try writing it yourself. You might need to study a bit first. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service and while I'm happy to help I will only do so if you make some effort. Please see the documentation in my last link.